# django and model`s property

Tags: python, django

I have a question. Will these two properties work different and how, I mean db hits.
for example, we have the model Article, that has a `ForeignKey` field `book`

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey("books.Book")
```

what is the best way to get an `author` by one of the prorerties:

```
@property
def author(self):
    if self.book:
        return self.book.author
    return None
```

or

```
@property
def author(self):
    book = self.book
    if book:
        return book.author
    return None
```

Comment: django and python-wise this would be equal. The actual hit is in your queryset method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Both of your options look functionally identical to me.  I'd go with option one, since it has one less line.  They're both going to require 2 queries:  one for the author object, one for the book.  But you can make it just one if you select the author object using select_related(), which will pre-join the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are defining a property on `Article`, the actual database hit depends on how `Article` querysets are retrieved. If you use `select_related([depth=2])` on your [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) while retrieving the `Article` objects, that would be the most optimal in terms of database hits irrespective of how you write the property. Both the ways you have listed have similar performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should just call

```
article.book.author
```

This call will query book object and cache it on article instance. So if you call article.book.id after that first call it will not run the second query.

Personaly I think that you should try to avoid hitting the database in model methods as much as possible. Because, as your application gets complicated, developers will just call the author method of your article even if they also have book model in their hand. because two property is virtually same.

Comment: what if `book` is `None`? Then this will throw `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'`. I do agree with your statement about queries inside your model. You really pointed something out good there what many people don't see.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this option because it makes only one query to the database:

```
@property
def author(self):
    authors = Author.objects.filter(book__article=self.id)[:1]
    return authors[0] if authors else None
```

Comment: But this solution will always make a query regardless of whether `select_related` is used.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes it is the preferred option. Moreover, if you are sure that in the process the request `author` field will not change, you can use something like `@memoized_property` instead of the `@property`.

Comment: @defuz sometimes is not good enough, give a specific example when this could be preferred, with a good reason. I can't see any advantage of this.

Comment: @KillianDS, 1. We do not know if we need `author` for each article model when we select `articles`. 2. Join tables `author` through `book` table can be an expensive operation (even with the use of indexes).

Comment: @defuz: that is a con for `select_related`, not for why not to use the original code (which is obviously a lot more clear than this). Also, how often will you retrieve a whole set of books, but only the author of one.

Comment: @KillianDS, original code first select from a database `book`, then select `author` (2 queries). It may be that I do not need a `book` model at all. My proposal execute a single query. Otherwise I do not understand why you need to create a property.

Comment: Also, if you have code with suspiciously many `.select_related(..)`, you should consider using non-relational databases (like mongodb).

Comment: You're saying that querying a **related** object is an indication you should not use **relational** databases? As for the other comment: if your main goal is to reduce queries, use select_related, if you do not want select_related because the lookup will be very infrequent, odds are quite tremendous your ugly code is a useless micro-optimization compared to the original code.

Comment: Actually `select_related` works as a selection the hierarchical document from non-relational database, which is usually much faster than query from a relational database with a lot of joins. The beauty of joins that you can decide when and what you need. `select_related([depth=...])` violates this principle. I think we should end this debate, because without a specific example it does not make sense.)

Comment: If you use queries, I think you should build a `Manager` instead of doing this inside your `Model`. Besides, it's really unnecessary and the question even provides a better solution in this case.